# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'( in nginx and php7)

Tags: mysql, sockets, nginx, php-7

Following nginx configuration file /defult
#

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;


     root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

        server_name 127.0.0.1;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
location /studentdesk {
       autoindex on;
}
        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
                location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php7.0-fpm:
#               fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
                location ~ /\.ht {
#               deny all;
        }
```

Above is the file setting . please help me solve this error.

I am useing php7.nginx,mysql in ubuntu 16.0 server.

How can I fix this? I am unable to to open mysql and same error in phpmyadmin